# Send struct with string by LoRa (Arduino)

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++, lora

I'm trying to send some data with LoRa but I only receive single chars (line by line) or float, int, byte...

I want to send "msg" like a string.

I have:

```c
struct DATA {
  char msg = "";
  int valor;
};
DATA MyData;
.
.
.
void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    MyData.msg = Serial.read();
    MyData.valor = 10;
    Transceiver.SendStruct((uint8_t*) &MyData, (uint8_t) sizeof(MyData));
    Serial.print("Sending: "); Serial.println(MyData.msg); Serial.println(MyData.valor);
  }
}
```

it works but if I send: "hello world", I will receive:

```
h
10
e
10
l
10
.
.
.
```

So I tried to make an aux variable:

```c
if (Serial.available() > 0) {
  char aux = Serial.read();
  MyData.msg += aux;
  MyData.valor = 10;
  Transceiver.SendStruct((uint8_t*) &MyData, (uint8_t) sizeof(MyData));
  Serial.print("Sending: "); Serial.println(MyData.msg); Serial.println(MyData.valor);
}
```

But I receive only unrecognized chars.

PS1: If I change struct char with a String, I receive only unrecognized chars.

PS2: I tried to make a "for" with the sizeof on receive to join the chars to make a string, but it doesn't work either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: char is one character. maybe you want an array of characters?

Comment: yes, I tried it too, but without success..

Comment: when I specify the vector size, the receiver print only unrecognized chars...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `MyData.msg` is defined as a `char` which is a single character instead of an `array[]`. You need to define your struct as:

```cpp
#define MAX_STR_LENGTH 20

typedef struct {
  char msg[MAX_STR_LENGTH] = '\0';  // an array of char
  int valor = 0;
} Data_t;

Data_t Mydata;
```

2. You are sending the struct data each time a char is received instead of of waiting for the whole string is received. Assuming the string you received from Serial is terminated with `\n`. You can read in the whole string by checking with the received char is an `\n` and only send the struct then.

```cpp
void loop() {
   static int i = 0;
   while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    char c = Serial.read();
    if (c != '\n') {
      MyData.msg[i] = c;
      i++;
    }
    else {
      // terminate the array with NULL terminator and send the struct
      MyData.msg[i] = '\0';
      MyData.valor = 10;
      Transceiver.SendStruct((uint8_t*) &MyData, (uint8_t) sizeof(MyData));
      Serial.print("Sending: "); 
      Serial.println(MyData.msg);
      Serial.println(MyData.valor);
      i = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Further reading:

[Array](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/array/)

[Nick Gammon on Serial](https://www.gammon.com.au/serial)

Comment: Testing again, I noticed that the first string sends ok, but the second string send only the first again. Example: first test (send - ok), second test (send - first test)

Comment: Sorry, `i` need to be reset after sending. I update the code.

Comment: I made further change to correct the code where `i++` only occured if the string is not completed receive, and `i` is set to zero once the struct is send. This should works.